# usar varias funciones de un controlador en una sola vista

Tags: laravel

voy iniciando el laravel y me encontrado con una duda respecto a controladores y vistas, ¿ es recomendable que en una sola vista se usen distintas funciones de un solo controlador ?

estoy intentando hacuer que las funciones de CRUD se manden a llamar en una sola vista para aleterar datos de una tabla

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Puedes chequear en la documentación de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#resource-controllers)